# How to use CSS Sprite in responsive layout?

Tags: css, responsive-design, sprite

There a few questions that revolve around my problem, but none of the answers pertain to what I'm trying to do. I'm using a sprite for my site logo by using a class on an anchor tag. Problem is that I have to define the pixel height and width and this prevents the logo from being responsive.

Here's the HTML:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/" class="logo-sprite"></a>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
a.logo-sprite {
    background: url('image_here.jpg') 0 0;
    display: block;
    width: 450px;
    height: 130px;
}

a.logo-sprite:hover {
    background: url('image_here2.jpg') 0 -140px;
}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: That's a really large sprite image!  You *are* allowed to use `em` or `%` instead of `px` on images/background-images if it is necessary in combination with `background-scale`.  SVG backgrounds might be a nicer choice than making a couple different scaled spritemaps.

Answer (score 0):

That's right. Since sprites, by definition are meant for fixed dimensions only (They are images after all), they cannot be "smoothly" used in fluid/responsive layouts.

They can be used in responsive layouts, as long as you keep making adjustments for each "level" in your media queries.

Comment: So the only/best option is to set a manual adjustment via media queries in the stylesheet?

Comment: @user1485728: As far as I know, yes. You should check for articles on http://css-tricks.com, they sometimes discuss it there, maybe there's an article you may find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have an idea.

You can use the `background-size` property to "lock" the sprite in place and stop more/less of it being shown than you want. Here is a rudimentary example:

```
background-position: 0px 0px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 190% 140%;
```

The only problem here is that images resize differently to elements like `Div`s and anchors so the height won't scale dynamically. I believe the only way to achieve this is to use JavaScript but I may be wrong.

Here's a rough example of how you might start going about something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/VW2dW/16/
If you resize the browser you will notice it successfully scales horizontally but not vertically which is a problem.